# using the form template in bootstrap for styling only

Tags: forms, bootstrap-4, laravel-blade

can I use only the layout of the form in bootstrap and have the input option frozen and the submit buttons behave like plain html button which redirects somewhere?
[image]

**Why I want this?**
So in the homepage I have resources which can be deleted pressing the delete button against them. On clicking the delete button the resource data is displayed like the layout of a form, of course I want typing inputs to be disabled, and a warning message on top, and YES and RESET option at the bottom. Since the form has a specific action assigned via GET method it will invariably perform that action irrespective of the choice selected. So if RESET is also selected the resource still gets deleted.
One option is to have the buttons as individual links with specific redirection properties but then I need to handcode the entire styling of the form.
Below is the code

```
  @elseif($layout=='delete')
    <div class="container-fluid mt-4">
      <div class="row">
        <section class="col md-7">
          <div class="card mb-3">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/05/05/19/53/keyboard-338502_1280.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Are you sure you want to delete</h5>
                <form action="{{url('/destroy/'.$student->id)}}" method="get">
                      @csrf
                      <div class="form-group">
                      <label>CNE</label>
                      <input  value="{{ $student->cne }}" type="text" class="form-control" name="cne" placeholder="Enter CNE">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                      <label>FirstName</label>
                      <input value="{{ $student->firstName }}" type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter the first Name">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Last Name</label>
                      <input value="{{ $student->LastName }}" type="text" class="form-control" name="LastName" placeholder="Enter the Last Name">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Age</label>
                      <input value="{{ $student->age }}" type="text" class="form-control" name="age" placeholder="Enter Age">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Speciality</label>
                      <input value="{{ $student->Speciality }}" type="text" class="form-control" name="Speciality" placeholder="Enter the speciality">
                      </div>
                      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="yes">
                      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="reset">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you want disable input, add readonly to your inputs :

```
 <input  value="{{ $student->cne }}" type="text" class="form-control" name="cne" placeholder="Enter CNE" readonly>
```

Second, now the type of your reset button = submit so when you click it, your form is submitted. Change your code :

```
<input type="reset" class="btn btn-warning" value="reset">
```

Comment: this partially resolves. However using type and value as "reset" only resets the form but stays on the same page. Ideally the action should return me to the homepage. What I am looking for is two different actions on the same form redirecting to two different routes depending on selecting "yes" or "reset".

Comment: Add one link instead of reset button. `<a href="">Return Back</a>`

Comment: also disabling input disables the php perser from reading the value and this error is thrown. `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'cne' cannot be null`

Comment: my mistake use readonly instead of disabled @code-mon